# Windows Phone 7.1: How to add & delete items from LongListSelector control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Windows Phone 7.1: How to add/delete items from LongListSelector control?

I am using a LongListSelector control from 'Windows Phone Toolkit'. The control is data bound to a ViewModel inherited from an ObservableCollection. When I try the following code:

```
MyObject mo = new MyObject("Name", "Description", "Value");
App.MyObjectsViewModel.Add(mo);
```

The ViewModel does seem to get updated but the LongListSelector does not update? What am I missing?

PS: I am new to Silverlight and WP7 development.

Following the XAML for the LongListSelector and the DataTemplates. The code is pretty much straight out of the Windows Phone Toolkit sample (removed some formatting related code to keep the post small)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupHeader">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="groupItemHeader">
    <Border>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" 
           Foreground="#FFFFFF" 
           FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
        </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="myobjectItemTemplate">
    <Grid>     
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<controls:PivotItem Header="myobjects">
<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="myobjectsList" 
    Background="Transparent"
    GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeader}"
    GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource groupItemHeader}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myobjectItemTemplate}"
    GroupViewOpened="LongListSelector_GroupViewOpened"
    GroupViewClosing="LongListSelector_GroupViewClosing"/>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

C# code behind for setting the ItemSource

```
var myobjectsByClassification = from myobjects in App.MyObjectsLibrary
        group myobjects by myobjects.Classification into c
        orderby c.Key
        select new PublicGrouping<string, MyObject>(c);

this.myobjectsList.ItemsSource = myobjectsByClassification;
```

Comment: Is `MyObjectsViewModel` an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Yes it is 'ObservableCollection<MyObject>'

Comment: Post the XAML to show the binding, also, if you're using the LongListSelector in grouped mode, post code to show how the grouped data structure is being created.

Comment: Updated the post to show the XAML bindings and code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the grouping code is only being called once somewhere in code behind. So the grouped collection is not updated when you add something to your ViewModel collection. The easiest way to handle this (but maybe not the most elegant) is to create your own `AddItem()` method for the ViewModel collection.

```
class MyViewModelObject
{
  void AddItem( MyObject obj )
  {
    App.MyObjectsLibrary.Add( obj );
    MyObjectsByClassification = from myobjects in App.MyObjectsLibrary
                                group myobjects by myobjects.Classification into c
                                orderby c.Key
                                select new PublicGrouping<string, MyObject>(c);
  }
}
```

Bind `MyObjectsByClassification` to `LongListSelector.ItemsSource` in XAML, and make sure you notify the LongListSelector of changes to the property by using `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I did try something similar but it did not work - no change to the LongListSelector view.

Comment: This is working now. I just added another line of code to explicitly bind the `LongListSelector.ItemSource` to     `MyObjectsByClassification` in code behind. May not be the most elegant solution but it is working. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

By using LINQ, the object you actually assign to `ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<T>` not an `ObservableCollection<T>`. LINQ-to-objects does not support automatic updating via `ObservableCollection`. After all, it returns a forward-only `IEnumerable<T>` and not a collection of any kind.

Change your ViewModel to actually expose an `ObservableCollection<PublicGrouping<string, MyObject>>` and bind your `ItemsSource` directly to that.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please help me with a sample code to implement what you have recommended. I tried ... couldn't get it work.

Comment: @bharath - I'd need to see a simplified version of your ViewModel to write a sample. Keep in mind that `PublicGrouping` would need to extend `ObservableCollection` if you plan on adding additional items to the groups after they're first created.

Comment: I am able to make it work - it will serve my purpose for now. However your response helped in understanding LongListControl behavior better. Thank You. I also found [this post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Dynamically-updating-a-data-bound-LongListSelector-in-Windows-Phone) on windowsphonegeek.com which should help others who have similar requirements: [link](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Dynamically-updating-a-data-bound-LongListSelector-in-Windows-Phone)